# getting error type any is not assignable to type never

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a state which looks like this

```
export interface IState {
  relationType: string
  relatedTableId: number | null
  foreignKey: string
  throughTableId: string
  required: boolean
}
```

and

```
this.state = {
  relationType: props.relation ? props.relation.relation_type : 'parent_relation',
  relatedTableId: _.get(props, 'relation.related_table.id', null),
  foreignKey: _.get(props, 'relation.foreign_key') || '',
  throughTableId: _.get(props, 'relation.through_table_id') || '',
  required: props.relation ? true :false
}
```

When I am trying to change state dynamically,

```
  handleOnChange(
    selected: ValueType<SelectOption>,
    key: 'relationType' | 'throughTableId' | 'relatedTableId'
  ) {
      const currentState = { ...this.state }
      currentState[key] = (selected as SelectOption).value;
      this.setState({ ...currentState })
  }
```

Here, TS is throwing following error

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

THis is what Select Option looks like (if this make any difference)

```
type SelectOption = {
  value: string | number
  label: string
}
```

This is the error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The keys you're trying to assign a value of type `string | number` to are not compatible with that type. They can either be assigned `string` or `number | null` but none of them can accept `string | number`.

```
relationType: string
relatedTableId: number | null
throughTableId: string
```

Unless you narrow the type of `selected.value` to make sure you:

1. know what type it is and
2. assign it to a field that is compatible with the narrowed type

TypeScript won't let you assign it to any of the fields you're trying to.

**EDIT**

As sam256 said the reason it says "is not assignable to `never`" is because `relationType`, `relatedTableId` and `throughTableId` have no overlap in types, so there is no type of value that can be assigned to all three of them.

This wouldn't be the case if `key` was `"relationType" | "throughTableId"` for example, because in that case `currentState[key]` could be assigned a value of type `string`, because:

```
currentState["relationType" | "throughTableId"]: string
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is identifying a real problem here.  What if you passed handleOnChange a "selected.value" that was a string, but a "key" value of "relatedTableId"?  Your function would be trying to assign a string to a number.  In other words you actually have a potential type mismatch in your code which TS is flagging.

I believe the wording of the error is because TS is inferring that currentState[key] is the intersection of string and number, which is never.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is pointing out that you're not doing all the required type checks. To expand on the the other answers, TS wants to see code that looks more like:

```
function handleOnChange(
    selected: ValueType<SelectOption>,
    key: 'relationType' | 'throughTableId' | 'relatedTableId'
) {
    const currentState = { ...this.state }
    const selectedValue = (selected as SelectOption).value
    if (key === 'relationType' || key === 'throughTableId') {
        if (typeof selectedValue === 'string') {
            currentState[key] = selectedValue
        }
    } 
    else {
        if (typeof selectedValue === 'number') {
            currentState[key] = selectedValue       
        } 
    }
}
```

The above uses explicit type checks which TS understands and it should compile without errors.